# How to specify BigDecimal scale and precision in schema when loading a Mongo collection as a Spark Dataset

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark-sql, schema, precision, bigdecimal

I am trying to load a large Mongo collection into Apache Spark using the Scala Mongo connector.

I am using the following versions:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.4.2"
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
```

The collection contains large integer decimal values greater than `1e13`.  The dataset I would like to obtain is a collection with a corresponding case class called `Output`, defined:

```scala
case class Output(time: Long, pubKeyId: Long, value: BigDecimal, outIndex: Long, outTxId: Long)
```

If I use MongoSpark.load without specifying the case class:

```scala
val ds = MongoSpark.load(sc, rc).toDS[Output]
```

then Mongo infers the schema by randomly sampling the collection.  This results in a random scale for the `value` attribute, and any documents whose `value` overflows the randomly-obtained scale have a missing `value` attribute in the resulting Dataset.  This is obviously not desired.

Alternatively, according to the [documentation for the Mongo Spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/datasets-and-sql/#explicitly-declare-a-schema), I can explicitly set the schema by specifying a case class as a type-parametrisation for `load` , e.g.:

```scala
val ds = MongoSpark.load[Output](sc, rc).toDS[Output]
```

However, in the case-class definition, I can only specify the type of `value` as `BigDecimal` which does not allow me to explicitly state the desired scale and precision.  The resulting schema uses the default precision and scale of (38,18), which is not always desired:

```
root
 |-- time: long (nullable = false)
 |-- pubKeyId: long (nullable = false)
 |-- value: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- outIndex: long (nullable = false)
 |-- outTxId: long (nullable = false)
```

This is in contrast to to the Spark SQL API, which allows the scale and precision to be specified explicitly using [`DecimalType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html), e.g.:

```scala
val mySchema = StructType(StructField("value", DecimalType(30, 0)) :: Nil)
```

How can I request a specific scale and precision for large decimal types in the schema, similar to the code above, when loading Mongo collections into Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by bypassing the `load` helper methods and calling `toDF(schema)` directly on the `MongoSpark` instance:

```scala
 val schema = StructType(
                             List(StructField("time", LongType, false),
                                  StructField("pubKeyId", LongType, false),
                                  StructField("value", DecimalType(30, 0), false),
                                  StructField("outIndex", LongType, false),
                                  StructField("outTxId", LongType, false)
                             ))
    val outputs =    
      builder().sparkContext(sc).readConfig(rc).build().toDF(schema).as[Output]
```

This results in the correct schema, and the data is read correctly into Spark without any missing values:

```scala
    outputs.printSchema()
```

```
 |-- time: long (nullable = false)
 |-- pubKeyId: long (nullable = false)
 |-- value: decimal(30,0) (nullable = false)
 |-- outIndex: long (nullable = false)
 |-- outTxId: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: In addition to being able to specify the scale and range, this method also has the advantage that we can specify that the field is non-nullable.  This is in contrast to  `load[Output]` which will always use a nullable field of type `Decimal(38,18)`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/bson-decimal128/decimal128.rst#bson-decimal128-implementation-details) and [this](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/dbspec.html), as far as I can tell, mantissa and exponent in Decimal128 are fixed size. Unless you can find evidence to the contrary it therefore does not make sense for MongoDB to permit specifying scale and precision for its decimals.

My understanding is relational databases would use different floating point types based on scale and precision (e.g. 32 bit vs 64 bit floats) but in MongoDB the database preserves the types it's given, so if you want a shorter float you'd need to make your application send it instead of the decimal type.

Comment: The issue is not how the value is stored internally in Mongo, but how it is represented in the *Spark* application.  The Spark SQL Schema specifies how Spark represents the data, not how the data is stored in Mongo.  In a Scala Spark application, when loading data from Mongo, BSON Decimal128 types are translated into [BigDecimal](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/math/BigDecimal.html) with a specific scale and precision.  It is important to be able to specify the scale and precision, because this will have ramefactions for the sizing of the cluster in terms of RAM and disk space.

Comment: See lines 309-313 of the following to see how the Mongo Spark connector infers BigDecimal scale and precision when using schema inference.  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/MongoInferSchema.scala

Comment: As clarification to the above, I should have said "*When loading data from Mongo into Spark*, the Spark SQL Schema specifies how Spark represents the data, not how the data is stored in Mongo."

Comment: I have no idea about that sorry.